# How to use elpy and non-python autocomplete

Tags: python, company-mode, auto-complete-mode, elpy

Elpy provides company-mode to handle autocompletion. The way it is set up, company only turns on when I am in something handled by Elpy.

If I enable auto-complete it works in non-python files, but then both company and auto-complete pop up, which is not desired behavior.

How can I enable company to still work within Elpy, but turn on auto-complete to be on elsewhere, and not clobber company?

Comment: Why would you want to use both?

Comment: @PythonNut Quite possibly because I don't entirely understand what I am doing. Lets say I do want to use company mode for everything. Do I just need to call `global-company-mode` after calling `elpy-enable` in my init.el? I know that elpy uses company mode, but is it only in scope when I'm in a python file, or will calling `elpy-enable` basically put it in place globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just enable `company-mode` globally without any problems with Elpy (if there are any, please do file a bug report!).

You can also use auto-complete in buffers other than Python mode buffers (auto-complete supports different backends from company-mode, so might be preferable for some), by removing `python-mode` from `ac-modes`. This will then not enable auto-complete in Python buffers.